# oh-my-zsh not fully loading - have to source .zshrc

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

https://streamable.com/07mqf

I have a video showing have it have to do to get this to work.

I have tried based on suggestions in stackoverflow to move the source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh after the POWERLEVEL9k command line parameters.  This did not work and even when I load the source file would not show the line as it should.

Here is my config file.
https://hastebin.com/otolobihuw.makefile

Answer (score 0):

Try sourcing the p9k theme file after setting all the p9k variables. You need to move
source /usr/share/zsh-theme-powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme
to the end of your zshrc file.

I'm also not really sure what conflicts there may or may not be with having an ohmyzsh theme set in addition to sourcing p9k, but if it works okay for you after manually sourcing your zshrc again then moving the loading of the theme to after all the theme settings should be sufficient.

I was answered in another forum.  This resolved my issue I just moved the powerlevel9k to the bottom of my .zshrc file.